# linking error with local derived objects in template functions

Tags: c++, templates, linker, g++

I'm having a templated function that uses a local class which is derived from another base class. When this function gets instantiated in different compilation units, the linker throws "multiple definition" errors for the default constructor and destructor.

The following is a boiled down version of some code that was causing me trouble. It consists of three files. It is meant to be valid(?) C++ code:

a.h:

```
struct foo {
    template <typename T>
    void f(const T&);
};

struct base {
    virtual ~base(){};
};

template <typename T>
void foo::f(const T&) {
    struct derived: public base {
      // derived(){}
      // virtual ~derived(){}
    };
    derived x;
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
void fa() {
    foo a;
    a.f(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
void fb() {
    foo a;
    a.f(1);
}
```

Compiling this generates a linker error because the constructor and destructor of derived are there twice:

```
$ g++ a.cpp b.cpp
/tmp/ccvPK1l5.o: In function `void foo::f<int>(int const&)::derived::derived()':
b.cpp:(.text+0x24): multiple definition of `void foo::f<int>(int const&)::derived::derived()'
/tmp/ccRb6RYO.o:a.cpp:(.text+0x36): first defined here
[...]
```

Interestingly, if you manually define the constructor and destructor of derived (by uncommenting the two lines), everything works fine.

Is there anything invalid in my code or is it a bug in gcc? I tried gcc 4.3 and 4.4, both are having the same issue.

For my real code I solved the situation by declaring "derived" as a global class as opposed to a local one inside f. But I would still be interesting in knowing what was going wrong and why so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: +1 for workaround first, ask later

Comment: but you do have header guards in place,right? edit: stupid me, if he hadn't it would've complained about foo first, nvm.

Comment: But I have no problems with this code...Maybe you have circular references?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification said `Member functions of a local class (9.8) have no linkage.` (C++0x 9.3p3), so this is probably a gcc problem.

However, it seems to be solved in g++4.5, because you example successfully passed compilation and link with g++ 4.5.2 (with or without the constructor and destructor commented):

```
$ cat a.h
struct foo {
    template <typename T>
    void f(const T&);
};

struct base {
    virtual ~base(){};
};

template <typename T>
void foo::f(const T&) {
    struct derived: public base {
      //derived(){}
      //virtual ~derived(){}
    };
    derived x;
}

$ cat a.cpp
#include "a.h"
void fa() {
    foo a;
    a.f(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}

$ cat b.cpp
#include "a.h"
void fb() {
   foo a;
   a.f(1);
}

$ g++ --std=c++0x --pedantic a.cpp b.cpp -o a
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)
```

Comment: The problem appeared only with the constructor and destructors *commented out*.

Comment: @bohan the link error didn't appear when I comment them out either.

Comment: I just installed gcc 4.5 and checked it. I also had a look at the object files using "nm". 4.4 creates normal symbols and 4.5 weak ones. So together with your quote from the standard (that also appears before c++0x) I'm pretty convinced it is indeed a gcc (pre 4.5) bug.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has anything to do with templates, because this often happens with functions that are defined in header files.  For example... if you made a function in your a.h and didn't even use it...

```
   int test()
   {
        static int foo=3;
        return foo;
   }
```

f you try to compile this. It will complain about this being a multiple definition. The way to fix it is to add inline i.e. like

```
   inline int test()
   {
        static int foo=3;
        return foo;
   }
```

This will also fix your case. The point to remember is that a function defined in a header file and included from multiple places will be compiled in each translation unit. That means when you link there will be multiple definitions.  If you don't want it to be a global function symbol you can make it inlined like I did above, or you can make it static.   If

you make it static the code will appear in every object file that uses it. If you make it inline it will be inlined (potentially) into every function.

Comment: That is exactly where templates differ from normal code. For templates, the code has to be present in the header file and the needed version of the template is instantiated and compiled in every compilation unit.
The symbol is then marked as a weak symbol (I think, that's the term) and the linker removes all the duplicates.

Comment: Template definitions need not be in the header file so they are not that different.  You can define template class members and template functions that are defined in one translation unit. Other translation units can use those definitions once the code is linked. The only issue is that if you only provide a definition in a cpp, then it had better explicitly instantiate all possible versions you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

What aselle said above is an interesting explanation, although the multiple definition in your example is not the 'f' function, but the 'derived' local class ctor and dtor. Anyway, as an alternative workaround, declaring the 'f' template member function as inline solves the linking problem on GCC:

```
  struct foo {
      template <typename T>
      inline void f(const T&);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to define all header-defined functions inline (it is not always the best attitude), you avoid multiple including on older compilers using preprocessor

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_
// code of a.h
#endif
```

or alternatively just

```
#pragma once
```

on the top of the file. I am using g++ 4.6 and your code passes compilation without errors, so upgrading is also good idea.